# how get a row index from gridview windows form when enter key pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

Below code does not return row index when i click cell(column content) and enter key is pressed.

```
  private void dataGridView_city_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            string grid_row = dataGridView_city.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In any context**, you can always refers the `CurrentCell` or `CurrentCellAddress` to get the row index of current row easily:

```
int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Index;
//or
int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.Y;
```